# LPAD and RPAD such that total length is 20 characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in a table where values are like this:

```
105,65
106,8
107
108,1234
```

Now I have to output it in 16,4 format removing the comma.

I tried

```
REPLACE(RPAD(LPAD(AMOUNT, 16, '0'), 20, '0'), ',', '')
```

But it is always right padding 4 zeros to the right which is not the expected result. In case there are 4 characters after the comma, no zero should be right padded.

If it can be done in one SQL statement it will be helpful for me. 
Also when I am replacing the comma, it is reducing one character.

Comment: What is `16,4` format?  What do you mean "remove" the comma?  Examples of the result you want would be very helpful.

Comment: `@GordonLinoff For example the first value should be 00000000000001056500

Comment: The second one should be 00000000000001068000

Comment: Can the downvoter care to clarify what is the downvote for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm tempted to convert this to a decimal and then a string:

```
select cast(cast(replace(amount, ',', '.') as decimal(20, 4)) as varchar(20))
```

I'm not quite sure if that does the padding you want.  Also, replacing the comma may not be necessary if the comma is already your decimal separator.

EDIT:

Now that the result is specified:

```
select lpad(10000 * cast(replace(amount, ',', '.') as decimal(20, 4)),
            20, '0')
```

Or, if `amount` is already a number (which it really ought to be):

```
select lpad(round(amount * 10000), 20, '0')
```

Comment: If the comma is already your decimal separator then you don't need the replace.  Actually, what is the type of `amount`?

Comment: Ah, Thanks, removing the REPLACE command worked. I was not aware of this CAST command.

Comment: Why is the multiplication with 10000?

Comment: @Mistu4u . . . Because you want four decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need LPAD or RPAD or anything like that. You just need TO_CHAR, with the proper format model.

For example:

```
select to_char(10000*105.65, '00000000000000000009') as form_num from dual;

FORM_NUM            
---------------------
00000000000001056500
```

If the input is a string, '4.105,65' (it shouldn't be, it should be a number; but IF it is a string), with period as thousands separator and comma as decimal separator, it can be converted to number without using REPLACE or anything like that. Again, use TO_NUMBER with the proper arguments, including the proper format model:

```
select to_number('4.105,65', '999G999D9999', 'nls_numeric_characters = '',.''') 
                                                                  as num from dual;

       NUM
----------
   4105.65
```

Then pipe the output of TO_NUMBER as the input to TO_CHAR from the first illustration.